# Can the Hulk's healing overcome supernatural afflictions?

Tags: marvel, vampire, the-incredible-hulk, werewolf

The Hulk's healing ability is, as far as I can tell, the strongest of any Marvel character to date.  While it is extremely difficult to injure him in the first place, if it does occur any injury regardless of severity heals almost instantly.  It's also been shown that the Hulk has some resistance to mystical energies, but could it overcome something like Vampirism, or Lycanthropy?  His healing factor has a (vaguely) scientific explanation of a constant regeneration of his cells fueled by his Gamma rage, but it is often shown in comics that science can be trumped by magic (i.e. Superman's weakness to magical forces)  Given that it would be nearly impossible for a regular vampire to even bite the Hulk even in a base, non-enraged state.  I would think it possible for say Dracula or Lilith, or any of the top tier vamps to, given the right circumstances, bite and infect the Hulk.  Has anything like this ever been shown before?

I am aware that the Hulk from the Marvel Zombies universe was infected, but I believe that was more of a scientific reason for the plague; I'm looking for a supernatural based ailment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**On the canon Marvel Earth-616, the answer would be yes, he would be immune to the infections used to spread the diseases of lycanthropy and vampirism.**

- Both diseases were born of interactions with demonic beings, black magic and/or genetic engineering and alien intervention and passed either through a curse or by infection.
- The Hulk's regeneration and natural resistance to magic linked to his incredible regeneration should make him proof against either.

**Wikipedia reference on [vampirism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_%28Marvel_Comics%29) in the Marvel Universe:**

> - The bite of a vampire transfers an unidentified enzyme found only within the saliva of a vampire into the bloodstream of the victim.
> - If a vampire drinks enough blood to cause a victim's death, this enzyme triggers a metabolic change within the victim's body, beginning with the production of a green liquid referred to as "ichor" into the bloodstream.
> - After roughly three days, enough of this liquid in the victim's body that it begins to course through the veins in the same way his or her blood once did.
> - The victim then returns as a newborn vampire and is capable of all the basic capabilities of ordinary humans, with the exception of being able to have children, plus a number of supernatural abilities of strength, speed, agility, endurance, senses, immortality, and healing factor.
> - However, if the victim retains sufficient blood to survive the vampire's attack, he or she begins to show signs of anemia because of the presence of the enzyme in his or her bloodstream.

**From the Marvel Wiki: [Werewolf by Night](http://marvel.com/universe/Werewolf_By_Night#ixzz2huwZVpqd) entry**

> - Following the [Cataclysm](http://marvel.com/universe3zx/index.php?title=Great_Cataclysm&action=edit&redlink=1), the [Fortisquian](http://marvel.com/universe3zx/index.php?title=Fortisquian&action=edit&redlink=1) colonizers from the planet Arcturus came to Earth to investigate the fate of the Savage Land, which had been created by the alien [Nuwali](http://marvel.com/universe3zx/index.php?title=Nuwali&action=edit&redlink=1) for the enigmatic [Beyonders](http://marvel.com/universe/Beyonders). A trio of colonizers based in the Savage Land acted as humanity's Caretakers.
> - Amongst many other activities, they created the modern incarnation of werewolves: combining advanced genetic re-engineering science with earthborn magic (apparently tapping into the Wolf-Demon's power), they bound the spirit and DNA of the captured wolf [Windracer](http://marvel.com/universe3zx/index.php?title=Windracer&action=edit&redlink=1) into a humanoid.
> - This hybrid, later known as [Greysire](http://marvel.com/universe3zx/index.php?title=Greysire&action=edit&redlink=1), spread this gift to humanity via scratches and bites, and then by heredity. The resultant race was known as brethren by wolves and werewolves by humanity, but the gift became a curse as man fell out of harmony with his primal self.

**The Hulk's regenerative powers allow him to instantly throw off any kind of infection without thought or effort on his part. His resistance to magical forces is equal to his ability to repel almost any other kind of energy so the diseases having magical origins should have no bearing on their effectiveness.**

**Most references use wording similar to the following:**

> **Regenerative Healing Factor:** The Hulk is capable of regenerating damaged or destroyed areas of his body with far greater speed and efficiency than an ordinary human. Wounds that would be deadly to most other creatures take a short period time for the Hulk to recover. **The Hulk's highly efficient physiology renders him immune to all known Earthly diseases.**

Comment: Supernatural ability of 'immorality'. If my browser history is anything to go by, I definitely have that one! :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure in one of the avengers cartoons, hulk actually does get infected with vampirism by Dracula, and Dracula hulks out too, but because of the gamma radiation of hulk's blood it works like UV light and cured himself by burning out all the vampiric blood by getting angry enough. It also nearly kills Dracula

Answer (score 3):

The only thing in the comics I've see even close to this is in the Ultimate Marvel line.

In the third series of *Ultimate Avengers* (Blade Versus the Avengers, issue 2) Bruce Banner's clone, known as "Nerd Hulk," was infected by vampires. In this continuity, Nerd Hulk has the same strengths and powers as Ultimate Hulk, except he's without the boundless capacity for rage, and therefore kind of useless. In the words of Ultimate Captain America:

"Look, you're forcing me to be more blunt than I want to be, but you fight like a scientist, Bruce... a *lady* scientist..."

But I digress. If it could happen to Nerd Hulk, it could probably happen to Ultimate Hulk. Ultimate Hulk is nowhere as near as powerful as regular continuity Marvel Hulk is, but he's much more powerful than regular continuity Marvel Hulk was at the same time in their publication histories, so who knows what could happen.

Comment: While not the real Hulk, "Nerd Hulk", as he has been code named, is a clone created by Tony Stark's older brother, Gregory from Banner's stem cells. This Hulk from the Ultimate universe was created from the cells exposed to the original Hulk serum, making him weaker and more vulnerable than the original augmented Hulk who had been given a second dose of the serum that gave him his powers.

Answer (score 0):

Lycanthropy is being turned into a werewolf right? Do you consider Wendigo's werewolves? If so Hulk was infected in Hulk #9 (2009). He was attacked by several Wendigo's and bitten. He turned into Wendihulk but was turned back to Hulk form by Brother Voodoo (a magician) within minutes. I would assume he would have fought off the infection eventually given the nature of his powers. I can post scans on request.

Hulk fought and killed hundreds of vampires after Fear Itself and was about kill Dracula before Betty stopped him. I don't recall him being bitten but the implication in this three issue tie in was vampires were no match for him in any way, shape or form.

Comment: I don't consider the Wendigo and a werewolve the same, but if I remember correctly the Wendigo is a supernatural curse all the same so your point is still valid.  However seeing as Jericho Drumm reversed the effects as opposed to Hulk's healing factor this doesn't actually answer my question.

Comment: The only other instance I can recall of a Hulk mutation was during Planet Hulk. In Incredible Hulk 99 (2006) he was infected by a spike monster. He started to protrude spikes but eventually managed to tear out the infection. In issue #103 Spike Elders fed off him which lead to him being mutated. Once they finished feeding he healed but I'm guessing that's a biological mutation and not a supernatural mutation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. Hulk can be bitten by a vampire but his gamma cells are stronger than the vampire cells so after couple of minutes he changes back. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Agents of smash the Hulk became a full Vampire because of the leader been Dracula's version of Renfield and in other episodes the Hulks became Wendigo's and demons

Comment: And…?  Try to actually answer the question.